# passing user defined parameter input in batch file to SQL file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, parameters

I want to know how it can be achieve I have a file `A.sql`.  `A.sql` has insert command with `WHERE` clause and update command with `WHERE` clause.

SQL file:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT columns FROM table2 WHERE col1 BETWEEN 'Value1' AND 'Value2'

UPDATE table1 SET (coluname) = (SELECT colname FROM table2 WHERE some_col = 'Value3')
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE some_col ='Value3')
```

User define `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3` while running batch file.

Batch file:

```
SET PRO=A.sql
sqlplus %Cond%@%HOMEDIR%sql/%PRO% >>%HOMEDIR%log/%log_file%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use passed values to the `*.sql`-file using `&1 &2 ... &n`.

Now depending on how the parameters are set by the user:

Using `set /p param1=` for user input during "runtime":

```
sqlplus %Cond%@%HOMEDIR%sql/%PRO% %param1% %param2% <etc> >>%HOMEDIR%log/%log_file%
```

If given as parameter use `"%~1" "%~2" <etc>`. Where `%1`stands for the first argument and `~` removes potential surrounding quotes.

You can as well modify those parameters and save them to a variable for later use:

```
set /a p1=%~1-1
set /a p2=%~2-1
sqlplus %Cond%@%HOMEDIR%sql/%PRO% %p1% %p2% <etc> >>%HOMEDIR%log/%log_file%
```

`/a` shows that an arithmetic operation beeing done so that 1 is subtracted.
For B.sql as asked for in the comment.

Comment: I want to pass param1, param2 value to another B.sql file. But values passed to B.sql file. 
If param1= 5 , param2= 6
IN A.sql  variable &1== 5 and variable &2 ==6. But in 
B.sql I want &1 = param1-1(5-1) == 4 and param2-1(6-1) == 5

Comment: user input value of param1 variable as 5, it will be passed to A.sql, so variable &1 in sql file will have value =5, same param2 value =6. I want to use the same value enter by the user at runtime and modify the param1,param2 values and pass it to another sql file B.sql.

Comment: in B.sql ... i can use WHERE id = (&1)-1 ??

Comment: Not sure about that but leave me a bit time for an edit.

Comment: Can i directly subtracted value in B.sql files .. Instead of using set /a p1=%~1-1 ... Can I use &1-1 for B.sql??

Comment: Why don't you just simply try it out?! I tested with sqlcmd and it seemed to be working.... But notice that you should do research before asking one question after another. You asked how to use params, and I told you. The question with B.sql was off-topic already! I will not answer all you follow-up-questions as well!